# Axiom schema of Replacement analogue for Von Neumann stage

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice, large-cardinals

I am working without Choice for the time being, so "cardinal" means "well-founded cardinal."

Let $\kappa$ be a strongly inaccessible cardinal. I want to show that the Axiom Schema of Replacement restricted to $V_ \kappa$ holds. That is, let $X \in V_\kappa$ and let $f: X \to V_\kappa$ be definable w.r.t. $V_\kappa$. I want to show $\operatorname{rng}(f) \in V_\kappa$.

I'm still new to set theory, so forgive me if this seems silly, but here's what I tried: I know that strongly inaccessible means there is no surjection $V_\alpha \to \kappa$ for any $\alpha < \kappa$, so my idea was to extend $f$ to a function $g:V_\alpha \to V_\kappa$. I think the fact that there's no surjection $V_\alpha \to \kappa$ means $\operatorname{rng}(g)$ has "holes," i.e. there's "missing" Von Neumann ranks, so maybe I can use this to show everything in the range has rank smaller than $\kappa$. But I'm having trouble making this formal.

Comment: "I know tht strongly inaccessible means there is no surjection $V_\alpha \to \kappa$ for any $\alpha < \kappa$" This is only half the definition of a strongly inaccessible cardinal - you also need regularity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct definition of *inaccessible* is "For every $x\in V_\alpha$, and $f\colon x\to\kappa$, $\operatorname{rng}(f)$ is bounded".

Note that this means that if $f\colon x\to V_\kappa$, then composing $f$ with the rank function is a function into $\kappa$, so it is bounded. Therefore the rank of $\operatorname{rng}(f)$ is bounded so it is an element of $V_\kappa$, and since $f\subseteq x\times\operatorname{rng}(f)$, it follows that $f\in V_\kappa$.

So indeed, we get *second-order* replacement holds in $V_\kappa$.

Comment: I understand your argument. The only thing is that Mark's definition of strongly inaccessible is the one I'm familiar with. How does one see they're equivalent? (Or at least the forward direction.) I'm trying to work out this detail right now but I don't know if my proof is good without Choice.

Comment: Your definition is missing regularity. Once you add that $\kappa$ is regular, $x$ maps cofinality if and only if $x$ maps onto $\kappa$.

Comment: I see that, because of regularity, the only way way we could have $\operatorname{rng}(f)$ unbounded is if $\operatorname{rng}(f)$ is equinumerous with $\kappa$. So, towards a contradiction, assume they are indeed equinumerous. What I'm tempted to do next is to choose a bijection $\operatorname{rng}(f) \to \kappa$ and compose it with $f$ and observe the composition is a surjection onto $\kappa$, which is impossible. But the thing is I don't know if I can choose a bijection without Choice.

Comment: If two sets are equipotent, by definition, there is a bijection between them. You can choose an element from a non-empty set in ZF, in particular that set of bijections.

Comment: Ah! I get it now! Thank you so much!